# How do production Cassandra DBA's do table changes & additions?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am interested in how the Cassandra *production* DBA's processes change when using Cassandra and performing many releases over a year.  During the releases, columns in tables would change frequently and so would the number of Cassandra tables, as new features and queries are supported.

In the relational DB, in production, you create the 'view' and BOOM you get the data already there - loaded from the view's query.

With Cassandra, does the DBA have to create a new Cassandra table AND have to write/run a script to copy all the required data into that table?  Can a production level Cassandra DBA provide some pointers on their processes?

Answer (score 1):

We run a small shop, so I can tell you how I manage table/keyspace changes, and that may differ from how others get it done.  First, I keep a text `.cql` file in our (private) Git repository that has all of our tables and keyspaces in their current formats.  When changes are made, I update that file.  This lets other developers know what the current tables look like, without having to use SSH or [DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/download-ops-dev).  This also has the added advantage of giving us a file that allows us to restore our schema with a single command.

If it's a small change (like adding a new column) I'll try to get that out there just prior to deploying our application code.  If it's a new table, I may create that earlier, as a new table without code to use it really doesn't hurt anything.

However, if it is a significant change...such as updating/removing an existing column or changing a key...I will create it as a new table.  That way, we can deploy our code to use the new table(s), and nobody ever knows that we switched something behind the scenes.  Obviously, if the table needs to have data in it, I'll have export/import scripts ready ahead of time and run those right after we deploy.

Larger corporations with enterprise deployments use tools like [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) to manage their schema deployments.  When you have a large number of nodes or clusters, an automated deployment tool is really the best way to go.